# How is the RDF based Heterogeneous Relational Database Integration work?

Tags: database, rdf, heterogeneous

My Question is **how I can integrate two Heterogeneous Relational Databases based on RDF?** Is that done just by transferring the two relational databases, one by one separately into RDF statements, and then save them into one RDF table? Or I have to do some integrations before I save them in the RDF database table?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at the [D2RQ](http://d2rq.org/) project. You can expose your two relational database with that middle-ware. Quoting the D2RQ page, D2RQ allows to:

- create custom dumps of the database in RDF formats for loading into an RDF store
- query a non-RDF database using SPARQL

This should work for you if your databases are not terribly big and it is a good approach if your databases are frequently updated. If you need to run queries accessing both databases you can use [SPARQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARQL) query federation. Very easy with [Jena/ARQ](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/service.html).

If your data is static or does not get updated too often. You can get better scalability by dumping the RDF triples and assert them into a native triple store ([Jena/TDB](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/index.html), [4store](http://4store.org), [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VOSRDF)). With any of these triple stores stores you can use SPARQL to access the data.